# Integration testing with spark server

Tags: java, testing, server, integration-testing, spark-java

I'm trying to IT my spark server. My intentions are to test all the controller functions.
I have thought about few options:
1. Set up a server that will start when running the tests, and terminate when the tests are over.

The problem with this solution is that I have to rewrite my whole server logic to the new server (we start server from scratch every time we set the server before the testing).

2. Initiate a controller from the test class (essential to initiate and not static call, in order to configure the right db to the controller) that will call the controller functions and check their answers.

This is my favorite one, but it  means that I have to mock a spark request. I'm trying to build a spark request, and spark response objects, to send to my controller, and haven't found a single way to do that properly (and how to send parameters, set url routes etc..)

```
@Test
 Public void testTry(){
   String expectedName = "mark";
   myController myCtl = new myController()
   Request req = null;
   Response res = null;

   String childName =      myCtl.getChildNameFromDB(req, res);

  assertEquals(childName, expectedName);
}
```

3. The last one is to do the exact logic of the controller function in the test, and instead of getting the parameters from the request, ill initiate them myself.

For example, instead of:

```
String username = req.params(""usrName")
```

It will be:

```
Strimg username = "mark"
```

But that solution will demand copying a lot of code, and you might miss a little code line which might make the test succeed when in reality, the controller function fails (or doesn't deliver as wanted).

What do you think about Integratiom testing a spark driven server? I'm open minded to new solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do integration testing, I would suggest to use your first approach, using a randomly chosen free TCP port and a HTTP client library (I often use the excellent [HttpRequest](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request) library to that effect).

The main issue with this approach is that since Spark API is static, you won't be able to stop/start the server between test cases/suites.